# How can I plot a sinc function correctly?

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, sampling, fourier

I am generating a rectangular pulse using a piecewise function on Matlab. I have listened to some advice to use a normalization coefficient and the amplitude appears correct now. However, my issue is that it seems that my Fourier Transform plot is squished at the origin. Can someone point out where did I go wrong? Thank you for taking the time.

My Code:

```
% Sampling Frequency
fs=1000;

% Time Variables of Piece-wise functions
t1=-1:1/fs:-0.5;
t2=-0.5:1/fs:0.5;
t3=0.5:1/fs:1;

% Evaluations of each time intervals
y1 = zeros(size(t1));
y2 = ones(size(t2));
y3 = zeros(size(t3));

% Combination of the time variables and functions
t=[t1 t2 t3];
f=[y1 y2 y3];

% Plot the rectangular pulse
figure(1);
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(t,f);

% Fourier Transform Plot
subplot(1,2,2);
% Frequency Domain between -10 and 10 using the size of the function (f).
freq=linspace(-10,10,size(f,2));
% Fourier Transform with normalizing coefficient (1/fs).
ft=fftshift(fft(f))./(fs);
plot(freq,abs(ft));
```

Comment: Maybe this page helps you to solve the issue - https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Fourier/Series/ExFS.html

Comment: Your frequency vector is incorrect. Should be something like `linspace(-fs/2,fs/2,size(f,2))`
If you want something not as "squished", decrease the width of the pulse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demonstration:

Your source code with modification @Jdip suggests in his comment and additional code to plot a abs(sinc()) response [-10:10]:

```
% Sampling Frequency
fs=1000;

% Time Variables of Piece-wise functions
t1=-1:1/fs:-0.5;
t2=-0.5:1/fs:0.5;
t3=0.5:1/fs:1;

% Evaluations of each time intervals
y1 = zeros(size(t1));
y2 = ones(size(t2));
y3 = zeros(size(t3));

% Combination of the time variables and functions
t=[t1 t2 t3];
f=[y1 y2 y3];

% Plot the rectangular pulse
figure;

subplot(1,2,1);
plot(t,f);
axis([-1.5 1.5 -0.2 1.2]);
grid on;

% Fourier Transform Plot
subplot(1,2,2);
% Frequency Domain between -10 and 10 using the size of the function (f).
freq=linspace(-fs/2,fs/2,size(f,2));
% Fourier Transform with normalizing coefficient (1/fs).
ft=fftshift(fft(f))./(fs);
plot(freq,abs(ft), 'linewidth', 1, 'linestyle', '-', 'r');

hold on;

% std sinc() ----------------------------------------------
x = -10:1/fs:10;
s = sinc(x);
plot(x, abs(s), 'linewidth', 1, 'linestyle', '--', 'b');

axis([-10 10 -0.2 1.2]);
legend('|sinc(squarewave)|','|sinc()|','location', 'northwest');
grid on;
```

[image]